# What time of year is best to plant trees?

Tags: trees

When is the best time of year to plant trees, specifically [birch trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betula_nigra)? I'm located in northern New Jersey, and have heard that fall is the best season for planting to ensure optimal tree health. Is this accurate? Are there advantages to waiting until fall versus planting in the warmer/dryer months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as lawyers say "It all depends".  You can buy birches as little whips with a tiny pot that is a few feet tall all the way up to large specimens in a wire basket weighing up to 1100 pounds.
Fall is a recommended planting time as it can be wetter and the ground is still warm which allows the plant to establish a root system during a period of the year when they are not putting energy into leaves.

How easy it is to water the plant and how likely you will are of greater importance for summer plantings.  If you plant a birch at the back of the lot where the hose doesn't reach and you go on vacation for a few weeks then it could dry out.  Small plants will die and larger plants will have a setback.

Some general notes about planting [Betula nigra](http://plants.connon.ca/11100004/Plant/53/River_Birch/)

- prefers acid soil and will show chlorosis in alkaline soils. Do you know your soil pH?
- should only be pruned in summer as it may bleed sap if pruned in winter or early spring
- will grow to 60' tall and 45' wide at maturity.  Do you have enough room?
- apply a mulch around the base of the tree if planted in an exposed or cold location
- when planting do not "improve" the soil.  Dig a hole, plant the tree so the soil level is the same as the soil in the container and backfill with the soil from the hole.  Only if the tree is leaning use at least two stakes that are 12" inches out from the trunk.  Tie to the stakes with a soft substance like old garden hose. Do not use wire which will rub the bark and create a failure point.
- after planting water and water often for the rest of the year

Comment: I'll add that the Arbor Day Foundation recommends that the hole be two to three times wider than the root ball and no deeper than the depth of the root ball, and that the hole should be shaped like a shallow bowl, not a cylinder.